ModuleNotFoundError: from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
I have a "test.py" that contains:
from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
I can run "test.py" successfully directly in Spyder/Anaconda-Python 3.11.
However, when I try to run "test.py" in the Windows Command Prompt, I get the message:

from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

I have already tried pip install google in the command prompt, and it states

Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\userName\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->google) (2.5)

I also tried python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" to check the returned file path for installed modules, and I could find all the following folders in the returned file path:

C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages


google
google_auth-2.25.2.dist-info
google-3.0.0.dist-info
protobuf-3.20.3.dist-info

What else could I be missing?
